# How to install node.js & angular.js on a google instance

Tags: angularjs, node.js, server, installation

How do i install node.js & angular.js on a google instance running CentOS7

I can't find Instructions that work. The instance has no GUI installed

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can access CentOS terminal and download dependencies, like in freshly installed Ubuntu we use `apt-get install npm` and `apt-get install node` to install npm and node and then with npm we can install further packages.

Use terminal for this, check this if this helps you [How To Install Node.js on a CentOS 7 server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server)

Once npm install is done, you can install angularJS or any other npm packages.

Hope it helps you